# Как реализовать SMP boot в своей ос?

Tags: c, ассемблер

За все время поиска ответа я наткнулся только на ассемблерную иницализацию smp, которая проводилась в 16-битном режиме. Я работаю с gnu-efi, который загружается в 64-битном режиме. Я начинающий в теме низкоуровнего программирования операционных систем, поэтому могу многого не понимать. Нужно ли мне переходить в 16-битный режим (Если это вообще возможно), чтобы включить ядра, либо можно сделать это каким то образом из x64? Я пробовал изучать репозитории github, но все примеры оттуда грузятся под биос, изначально находясь в 16 битном режиме, соответсвенно, используя этот способ без ограничений.
[Вариант из текста выше (на русском, что странно)](https://coderoad.ru/48763883/APIC-multi-core-startup-Protocol-%D0%B8-ICR-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81)

Comment: "на русском, что странно" - это автоперевод с английского stackoverflow, если нажать там на "источник", то перекинет на оригинал: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48763883/4752653

Comment: Возможно, поможет то, как это делается в линупсовом ведре, которое втыкает SMP на довольно поздних этапах инициализации, далеко после перехода в 64-битный режим. Процедура инициализации здесь: https://github.com/0xAX/linux-insides/blob/master/SUMMARY.md , собственно включение здесь или где-то рядом в исходниках ядра: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/kernel/smpboot.c